# as3 Vector with init values

Tags: actionscript-3, vector

I want to *instantiate* a `Vector.<Number>` with two values of `1.0`

You might think I would do `Vector.<Number>(1.0, 1.0);` but that only traces `0`

Is what I'm trying to do possible? If so, how? Or am I stapled to the routine of using `.push` ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This one is even shorter:

```
var vec:Vector.<Number> = new <Number>[1.0, 1.0];
```

Comment: @32bitkid would have gotten the check for being the first to answer (call it luck). However, for whatever reason, your way of instantiating is quite a bit faster.

Comment: @Jackson The reason is this: `Vector.<Number>([Array])`parses the specified array to return a vector with init values, while "my way" simply generates a vector without any parsing.