# Does initializing a Vector with an array of values in AS3 partially defeat the purpose of a Vector?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, vector, initialization, instantiation

Take the following code:

```
m_vectSpaces = new Vector.<Vector.<Space>>(9);
m_vectSpaces[0] = Vector.<Space>([
        null,
        null,
        SpaceFactory.produceSpace(Space.BLANK, new Block()),
        SpaceFactory.produceSpace(Space.BLANK, new Block()),
        SpaceFactory.produceSpace(Space.BLANK, new Block()),
        SpaceFactory.produceSpace(Space.BLANK, new Block()),
        SpaceFactory.produceSpace(Space.BLANK, new Block())]);
```

As far as I've seen, it looks like this is pretty much the only way to instantiate a Vector with a bunch of initial values (overlooking the multidimensional aspect).  The problem here is that this is all evidently being turned into an Array before the Vector is completely initialized.

But aren't Vectors designed to largely replace Arrays as a much slicker, more efficient alternative?  Is doing this a particularly bad idea, and is this partially defeating the whole purpose behind using a Vector?  Is there a better way to do this, or am I particuarly missing something?  Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [as3 Vector with init values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864773/as3-vector-with-init-values)

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that question.  In that question, they're asking how to instantiate a Vector with initial values.  I already know how to do that.  In this question, I'm asking about whether doing so, at least in the way that I was aware of, were something that needed to be avoided essentially.  People really need to stop crying wolf on these things.

Comment: Or perhaps you have to read the answer a bit more thoroughly to see that your question was answered there, as well. You can also go and edit both questions and answers to include new information, you know...

Comment: Duplicate questions are what you're supposed to go after, not duplicate answers.

Comment: Before I try to drop this, I'm not talking about just mentioning that there was another answer out there that might be applicable though.

Comment: No reason to get mad. You could easily modify the other question and add some of the info you were looking for, which would make it all the more valuable for others. It's about keeping this a real knowledge base, not policing around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you can use the `new <T>[]` syntax to create a new Vector with initial content:

```
var vec:Vector.<Space> = new <Space>[/* your, items */];
// --------------------------^ Notice the lack of 'Vector.' before here.
```

Your example uses the global [`Vector()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#Vector%28%29) method to create a Vector from an array.